# Using JQuery plugin inside own script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to use [AjaxQ plugin](https://github.com/Foliotek/AjaxQ) which has MIT license. But I don't want to include one more js file and want to insert `$.ajaxQ` function inside my js file.

Function is like this: https://raw.github.com/Foliotek/AjaxQ/master/ajaxq.js

Is it possible to declare that code like this:

```
public functon ajaxQ(qname, opts) {
...
}
```

And use that like this:

```
ajaxQ("myqueue",myopts);
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Do you mean you want to use AjaxQ without jQuery?

Comment: No I'm ok with the jQuery. I only want to put that code snippet into my js file.

Comment: I suppose you could do `window.ajaxQ = $.ajaxQ;` If all else fails, `function ajaxQ( qname, opts ) { return $.ajaxQ( qname, opts); }`

Comment: but why not call direct, do you want to implement extras to the ajax routine?

Comment: I have too many js files and I don't want to increase it one. I want to put that snippet into my code but I couldn't find how to declare function inside js fle.

Comment: I don't see what the number of files has to do with calling it with or without the `$`.

Comment: you could just implement miniajax http://code.google.com/p/miniajax/

Comment: @codelio sorry for misundertanding. $. is ok.

Comment: If you're concerned with the number of requests, just throw the ajaxq plugin at the bottom of another file that gets added after jQuery. Also take a look into javascript minify/combiner when you put the application into production to minimize requests.

Comment: You can copy content of `https://raw.github.com/Foliotek/AjaxQ/master/ajaxq.js` in your own js. No problem. And you can use it the same way `ajaxQ("myqueue",myopts);`

Answer (score 0):

There's no significant difference between:

```
<script src="URL"></script>
```

and

```
<script>
// copy of contents of URL
</script>
```

Assuming the MIT license allows copying in this way, you can merge the code of the plugin into your file like this.

If you want to put it in a JS file rather than HTML, you can simply append the code to one of your local JS files.